# Virtual Memory traversal in Linux kernel 6.1.x while loading Kernel modules

Tags: linux-kernel

Aim:
For any particular process, I want to calculate the total size of its(the process') allocated virtual address space i.e sum of all of its Virtual memory address space.

Question: From Kernel 6.1 ahead there exists no **vm_next** pointer in vm_area_struct. So the given code giving compiler error.
So how can I traverse all the vm_area_struct assigned for a particuler process and achieve the above mentioned Aim?

My code:

```
static int __init init(void)
{
    
    struct task_struct *task;
    struct mm_struct *mm;
    struct vm_area_struct *vma;
    unsigned long virt_size = 0;

    ...
    ...


    mm = get_task_mm(task);

    // Iterate through the VMAs and calculate sizes
    for (vma = mm->mmap_base; vma; vma = vma->vm_next) {
        virt_size += vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start;
    }

    printk(KERN_INFO "PID: %d, Allocated Virtual Address Space: %lu KB\n", target_pid, virt_size >> 10);
    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the linked list formed by `vm_next` and `vm_prev` in `vm_area_struct` was removed in 6.1 because the same functionality is already present in the recently introduced maple tree. [Here's the commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=763ecb035029f500d7e6dc99acd1ad299b7726a1).

There seem to be two main ways to walk the VMAs now:

- Using a "maple tree operation state" (`struct ma_state`) to iterate the maple tree manually with `mas_find()`, `mas_for_each()` and others.
- Using [`struct vma_iterator`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1/source/include/linux/mm_types.h#L806) and the associated helper functions/macros: `for_each_vma()`, `vma_next()`, `vma_prev()`. This still uses a `ma_state` under the hood but provides a more friendly interface.

Here's an example:

```c
struct vm_area_struct *vma;
VMA_ITERATOR(iter, mm, 0);

for_each_vma(iter, vma) {
    virt_size += vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start;
}
```